# How to add series of keys on an Entity? Openjpa

Tags: java, db2, jpa-2.0, primary-key, openjpa

I have this entity named product. Is there a way to add a series of multiple keys? Like A key for Serial Number, a key for Serial Number and Model, a key for Model etc.  How can you do this? Thank you very much.

```
*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package lotmovement.business.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Version;

/**
 *
 * @author god-gavedmework
 */
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long product_Id;

    @Column(name = "SERIAL_NUMBER", nullable = false,length = 30)
    private String serial_Number;

    @Column(name = "DATE_ASSEMBLED", nullable = false,length = 10)
    private String date_Assembled;

    @Column(name = "TIME_ASSEMBLED", nullable = false,length = 20)
    private String time_Assembled;

    @Column(name = "MODEL", nullable = false,length = 20)
    private String model;

    @Column(name = "BATCH_ID", nullable = false,length = 6)
    private int batch_Id;

    @Column(name = "PROCESS_CODE", nullable = false,length = 3)
    private int process_Code;

    @Column(name = "DC_POWER_PCB_SERIAL", nullable = false,length = 20)
    private String dc_Power_PCB_Serial;

    @Column(name = "CONTROL_PWER_PCB_SERIAL", nullable = false,length = 20)
    private String control_Power_PCB_Serial;

    @Column(name = "MAINS_POWER_PCB_SERIAL", nullable = false,length = 20)
    private String mains_Power_PCB_Serial;

    @Column(name = "BLOWER_SERIAL", nullable = false,length = 20)
    private String blower_Serial;

    @Column(name = "HEATERPLATE_SERIAL", nullable = false,length = 20)
    private String heaterPlate_Serial;

    @Column(name = "LAST_PROCESS", nullable = false,length = 3)
    private String last_Process;

    @Column(name = "LAST_DATE", nullable = false,length = 20)
    private String last_Date;

     @Version
    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_TIME")
    private java.sql.Timestamp updatedTime;

    public Timestamp getUpdatedTime() {
        return updatedTime;
    }

    public void setUpdatedTime(Timestamp updatedTime) {
        this.updatedTime = updatedTime;
    }


    public Long getProduct_Id() {
        return product_Id;
    }

    public void setProduct_Id(Long product_Id) {
        this.product_Id = product_Id;
    }

    public String getSerial_Number() {
        return serial_Number;
    }

    public void setSerial_Number(String serial_Number) {
        this.serial_Number = serial_Number;
    }

    public String getDate_Assembled() {
        return date_Assembled;
    }

    public void setDate_Assembled(String date_Assembled) {
        this.date_Assembled = date_Assembled;
    }

    public String getTime_Assembled() {
        return time_Assembled;
    }

    public void setTime_Assembled(String time_Assembled) {
        this.time_Assembled = time_Assembled;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int getBatch_Id() {
        return batch_Id;
    }

    public void setBatch_Id(int batch_Id) {
        this.batch_Id = batch_Id;
    }

    public int getProcess_Code() {
        return process_Code;
    }

    public void setProcess_Code(int process_Code) {
        this.process_Code = process_Code;
    }

    public String getDc_Power_PCB_Serial() {
        return dc_Power_PCB_Serial;
    }

    public void setDc_Power_PCB_Serial(String dc_Power_PCB_Serial) {
        this.dc_Power_PCB_Serial = dc_Power_PCB_Serial;
    }

    public String getControl_Power_PCB_Serial() {
        return control_Power_PCB_Serial;
    }

    public void setControl_Power_PCB_Serial(String control_Power_PCB_Serial) {
        this.control_Power_PCB_Serial = control_Power_PCB_Serial;
    }

    public String getMains_Power_PCB_Serial() {
        return mains_Power_PCB_Serial;
    }

    public void setMains_Power_PCB_Serial(String mains_Power_PCB_Serial) {
        this.mains_Power_PCB_Serial = mains_Power_PCB_Serial;
    }

    public String getBlower_Serial() {
        return blower_Serial;
    }

    public void setBlower_Serial(String blower_Serial) {
        this.blower_Serial = blower_Serial;
    }

    public String getHeaterPlate_Serial() {
        return heaterPlate_Serial;
    }

    public void setHeaterPlate_Serial(String heaterPlate_Serial) {
        this.heaterPlate_Serial = heaterPlate_Serial;
    }

    public String getLast_Process() {
        return last_Process;
    }

    public void setLast_Process(String last_Process) {
        this.last_Process = last_Process;
    }

    public String getLast_Date() {
        return last_Date;
    }

    public void setLast_Date(String last_Date) {
        this.last_Date = last_Date;
    }


}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this and what do you perceive as the benefit?

Comment: In DB2 database. There is a thing called logical file. It is connected to the table. In a table you can have many logical files. For the table product, I can have a logical file that has a key for model, another I can have a key for serial number and another a key for both model and serial number. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045254/as-400-db2-logical-file-vs-table-index)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is fundamentally incorrect.  A Key should be a unique identifier for an instance of entity.  In your example, you want to have a key for "Model", it simply doesn't sounds right.

If you mean something else for "Key", please clarify and we may further discuss on it.

Comment: I came from a DB2 Database and you can have as many keys on a table... sets of keys. And why would i not be allowed? Serial_Number Field in the product is also unique in the Business side of it. you can check my answer for Romski I also gaved a good link for logical files. It is like I have a primary key called product_id but I still have more secondary keys like model etc.

Comment: for serial number it may be reasonable, but it is obviously not for "model" itself.  afaik, logical file is similar to "view" in other DB.  Just use your example, what are you going to expect for the "logical file" with key of "model"? each "model" will give you multiple product and it is obviously not a "key".  Instead of asking for "how to have multiple keys for entity" which doesn't seems logical, can you tell us what are you trying to achieve? You don't need to make "serialNumber" as key for you to find a "product" with certain serialNumber anyway.

Comment: I want to have two 3 keys for the entity. 1. The product_id which I already have. 2. The Serial Number Key because Serial Number Key is also unique and it is found in the textfield so I needed this record to use find() for update. 3. The model, to retrieve lots of records. (maybe I will just use JPQL for this). I am still new to this and I am relating it to my previous skill. Thank you.

Comment: You can just query by serial number/model/etc by query.  Like: `from Product where serialNumber = :someValue`  You simply don't need those "key" to make it works.

Comment: I already now that. What I don't know it to have more sets of keys in an Entity.. If that could be possible.

Comment: Okay, I get your point now. The Key as defined in an Entity is different from the Key definition in DB2. Maybe I will re ask my question this way... I was planning to have lots of this in an entity if this is possible or this is how you guys do it?

@@Entity
public class Project {
    @@EmbeddedId ProjectId id;
     :
}
 
@@Embeddable
Class ProjectId {
    int departmentId;
    long projectId;
}

Comment: In brief, no. You should consider only one identifier for each entity.  I believe in JPA there is probably no way to denote a "unique constraint/index" as what you are looking for (and I don't feel it is really needed anyway).  The best you can get is extract the combination of the new keys to a new "entity", which contains only the "key" itself and reference to the actual entity.  But I think it rarely help in making a better design though